# Is it possible to get "execution time consumption" information from gcda files?

Tags: gcc, report, profiling, gcov

As I know compiling code with `-fprofile-arcs` flag makes to generate `.gcda` file after this code execution. Together with `-ftest-coverage` flag and then `.gcno` file after compilation, it is possible to get information about what code was executed and how many times and get so called code coverage report.

Is it possible to get in similar way from `.gcna` files profile information similar to `gprof`, like functions calls count and execution time information?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid to say so but you are mistaking the terminologies here.

GPROF: It is a C/C++ program profiler. Whose purpose is to generate the profiling information for a particular execution, which consists of performance statistics like the control flow between different functions and there relationship with the propagated time consumed by the parent function and the child functions individually as well. So, the focus here is to find performance degrading points in a program.

Where as,

GCOV: It is a C/C++ coverage analysis tool. Whose purpose is to get the counts of execution for each statement, branches and blocks. So, the focus here is to just get the coverage stats.

Hence, the moral of the story is that these two tools have different purpose of life. ;)

If you wish to get both the information you can go with gprof though it has it's limitations at a lot of scenarios, it will get you the coverage information too with the method level granularity.

Comment: I tried `gprof`, but since it uses the `SIGPROF`, it completely destroys all the code I have since I wait for all sorts of events and all those calls do not check whether `errno` is `EINTR` on return. It's a LOT of work to 100% comply to that only to be able to run `gprof`. Instead, I've been using vtune (by Intel) and that doesn't require me to redesign 99% of my code.